# Sortable columns in embedded rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a jsp page containing a rich:dataTable with some data regarding my clients.
In each row I have another rich:dataTable containing some commission rates for the current customer.
The code is something like this:

```
            <rich:dataTable id="clientList" value="#{clientsBean.model}" var="client" rows="15">
                <rich:column id="nameColumn">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.manageclients_client_name}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText id="name" value="#{client.name}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column id="clientRatesColumn">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.manageclients_client_rates}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:dataTable id="clientRates" value="#{client.clientRates}" var="clientRate">
                        <rich:column id="clientRateProduct" sortable="true" sortBy="#{clientRate.product.qualifiedName}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.manageclients_rate_product}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{clientRate.product.qualifiedName}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        ...
                    </rich:dataTable>
                </rich:column>
                ...
            </rich:dataTable>
```

As you can see the embedded rich:dataTable (id=`clientRates`) contains a sortable column (id=`clientRateProduct`).
My problem is that if I click on the sort icon in the `clientRateProduct` column for the current client **all** `clientRates` dataTables will be sorted (not just the one for the current client).
I want the sort action to be performed just on the current `clientRates` dataTable. Can anybody please suggest a solution ?

I use RichFaces 3.2.2.SR1. & Tomcat 6.0.29

Answer (score 0):

you should encapsulate the inner data table with

```
<a4j:region renderRegionOnly="true" >
```

so only it will be updated from the ajax request

Comment: Thanks you Aba Dov. This does work with RichFaces 3.3.3.Final. Unfortunately I'm stuck with RichFaces 3.2.2.SR1 for now.